# Pylons Routes url_for for a map.resource

Tags: python, routes, pylons

How do I get the get, post, put and delete URLs for a restful routes resource using `url_for`?

For example, how do I get the PUT URL for a resource with id=1, and routes defined in `routing.py` like so:

```
map.resource('user', 'users', controller='user')
```

I know the correct URL is `/users/1`, but I don't want to hard code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://routes.groovie.org/restful.html

```
url('user', id=1)
```

should give you '/users/1'

Comment: Thanks! for some reason didn't find that page.

Answer (score 0):

In routes.py your route should be:

```
map.resource('user', 'users/{id}', controller='user' action="some_action")
```

and in your controller you can get this URL with `url_for` like this:

```
url_for(controller="user", action="some_action", id=1)
```

Ref: *[Chapter 9: URLs, Routing and Dispatch](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html)*, Pylons book.

I must warn you that this was used in Pylons 0.9.7, but it is not used in Pylons 1.0. `url_for` and `redirect_to` are redesigned. If you want to redirect in your controller you must write:

```
redirect(url(controller="user", action="some_action", id=1))
```

Or in your case:

```
url(controller="user", action="some_action", id=1)
```

Ref.: *[Pylons 1.0 Released](http://pylonshq.com/articles/archives/2010/5/pylons_10_released)*